# Cannot use installed java 3d

Tags: java, netbeans, java-3d

hi i'm trying to use java 3d in both command prompt and in netbeans. I have a win8 64 bit computor. I installed j3d-1_5_2-windows-amd64.exe. and it got installed inside java folder in a folder called Java3D. then I added an environmental variable as CLASSPATH and the values are C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar. 
my file get compilled without errors when I try to runit from command prompt using the command java -cp . Hello3d it gives a calss not found error for javax/media/j3d/Node. and when i try to import 3d libraries from netbeans it gives an error on j3d after import com.sun. the following is the class I compiled from command prompt. please tell me what i'm doing wrong. thanx in advance

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
public class Hello3d {
public Hello3d()
{
   SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
   BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
   group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
   universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
   universe.addBranchGraph(group);
}
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   new Hello3d();
}
} // end of class Hello3d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an obsolete version (1.5.2) of Java3D, this version is no longer maintained since a few years. Please uninstall it and install the latest version (1.6.0). Follow my instructions [here](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/).

Comment: Thanx but I have to use the 1.5.2 version for my assignment. I found my mistake. I have forgotten to give the current directory in the classpath now it's working. thanx again for the reply.

Comment: What is strange is that I don't see how Java 3D 1.5.2 knows where to find its native libraries which are necessary to make it work as you don't talk about the Java library path. Anyway, I'm happy to know it works for you and I advise you to tell your teacher to use a more recent version. Java3D 1.5.2 simply crashes on some machines under Windows 7 and 8, for example with Intel Q35 Express. Java3D 1.6.0 contains tons of fixes. Good luck.

Comment: Are those files for Java 1.6.0 just 3 files? j3dcore, j3dutil, vecmath?

Comment: @JimmyLee j3dcore, j3dutil and vecmath are the 3 sub-projects that compose Java3D. The necessary files including the third party dependencies are listed in my instructions above. A lot more than "just" 3 files are required to run a Java3D application.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs perfectly in my eclipse environment using java3d version 1.5.2.
It shows an ugly cube seen from one side only, red faced.

I guess you need to set the path to the native libraries that java3d needs.

Regrettably, I don't know how to do this on windows (R).
Regrettably I have not enough reputation to put this into a comment rather than an answer.

If anyone with enough reputation cares, please turn this answer into a comment.

Comment: Using Java 3D 1.5.2 is a bad idea anyway, it's obsolete, rather use Java 3D 1.6.0.