# NoClassDefFound Error javax/media/j3d/Node

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, java-3d

I have installed `java version 1.6` on my `windows 7` . I have Java Deployment `Toolkit 8.0.450.15 11.45.2.15` plugin installed on my `firefox` . I have installed `java3d 1.5.2 api` . I have set paths for both java and java 3d . Still when I click [here](http://java3d.org/howto.html) it is showing that I have java installed but not `java-3d`.

It is giving `error- NoClassDefFound Error javax/media/j3d/Node` .

Comment: Java3D 1.5.2 is obsolete, please look at my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26337893/458157